# web оболочка для mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, cms, gui, веб-программирование

Всем доброго дня. Посоветуйте есть ли бесплатные, открытые web оболочки по типу xataface, vfront, nubilder которые генерировали web оболочку для моей уже существующей бд на mysql. 
Нужна максимально простая тк пользоваться будут не технические пользователи. 
Из вышеперечисленных очень понравилась xataface, но под winserver она отказывается у меня корректно устанавливаться. 
Возможно есть какие либо модули для CMS?

Comment: Для mysql хорошая web-оболочка phpmyadmin

Comment: После всяких phpmyadmin, MySQL Workbench и т.д. всеравно вернетесь к командной строке, потому что удобнее, быстрее и практичнее этого ничего нет.

Comment: Пользоваться будут "не технические" пользователи, это важно, у phpmyadmin и Mysql workbench слишком тяжелый для этого интерфейс. Нужно всего навсего редактировать записи, и вести по ним поиск.

Comment: Подозреваю, разработать собственное решение быстрее, чем ответ здесь получить)